# which is the best practice to use for Image gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, image-gallery

In my app which i am developing now has the Image Gallery where it consist of lot of albums and multiple images per album.

which is the best practice to use for Image Gallery? where i am planning to create a tableview for album listing and a navigating to a new View Controller taping on album. is that good way of creating albums?

and i'm using AFNetwork how to cache the images in the background so that the performance of the application will not effect.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot if third party image gallery libraries available for iOS. Following are few of them :

[FGallery-iPhone](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone)

[UIPhotoGallery](https://github.com/ethan605/UIPhotoGallery)

[MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

[Image-Gallery](http://code4app.net/ios/Image-Gallery/4f67f4546803fa6d45000001)

If above ones doesn't serve your purpose you can always create a custom gallery view that serves your purpose.

Comment: without using third party libraries is it not possible ?

Comment: Its always possible. You can use already built ones to save your time. You can customise them as per your requirement based on their licence agreement.

Comment: okay okay you are right. ll check with the above libraries . thanks for your input :)